# Python3 using pyyaml: How can I put a dictionary path for a yaml scrape into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

I've been racking my brain on this issue and am looking to the masses for some advice.   I'm in the process of building out a yaml validator using python3 and the pyyaml library.

```
    with open(r'/Users/somepathtoyaml/yaml_file.yaml') as file2:
    documents = yaml.load_all(file2, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    for doc in documents:
        try:
            a_string = ['lvl1']['lvl2']['lvl3']
            if doc(a_string) == 'whatToCompareAgainst':
                print('this matches')
            else:
                print('Expected: ' + 'whatever we expected')
                print('Actual: ' + doc(a_string)
            except KeyError:
                pass
```

Whenever I try to run something like this the script fails.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign something to a variable, it needs to have a valid type. `['lvl1']['lvl2']['lvl3']` isn't a valid type. You're using it as a "yaml path" but Python sees it as three lists containing one string each so you can't assign that to a single variable. From your question, nothing here seems to be dynamic, so I think you could just use the chained slices in your if statement like below:

```py
with open(r'/Users/somepathtoyaml/yaml_file.yaml') as file2:
    documents = yaml.load_all(file2, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    for doc in documents:
        try:
            if doc['lvl1']['lvl2']['lvl3'] == 'whatToCompareAgainst':
                print('this matches')
...
```

You might also adjust your try/except structure. Instead of passing when you get an error, you should at least print it so you can see what is going wrong. For catch-all Exception blocks I often use:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Encountered Error: {e}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'll make my changes.   Here is the error message I receive. '"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". So the key problem that I'm trying to do is take that line with ['lv1']['lv2']['lv3'] etc  and put that into a variable.  But what happens is when I then try to do doc(a_string) that's where the head banging begins.  It seems like it's taking it all as a string vs what I need which is basically the yaml path

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just do doc['lvl1']['lvl2']['lvl3'].

Comment: So i can do that but the problem is I’m going to have another function that needs to pass information into this function do the doc['lvl1']['lvl2']['lvl3'] could come in as that but the next iteration could be doc['lvl6']['lvl7']['lvl8'][‘lvl9’]

Comment: It might help if you included the function so I can see what arguments you are using.